# get Dataframe Index column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1:

```
           Name
Date           
2012-11-26    a
2012-11-27    a
```

df2:

```
      Date Name
2012-11-26    a
2012-11-27    a
```

How can I get `df2` from `df1`?

I tried to use:

```
df1.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True)
```

It doest not match want I want.

Comment: I think what makes it not work is the 'level' option you pass. Since your index isn't a Multi-index, don't bother with levels. (and plz consider accepting jezrael's answer if it matches your problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df2 = df1.reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {'2012-11-27': 'a', '2012-11-26': 'a'}})
df1.index.name = 'Date'
print (df1)
           Name
Date           
2012-11-26    a
2012-11-27    a

df2 = df1.reset_index()
print (df2)
         Date Name
0  2012-11-26    a
1  2012-11-27    a

df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
print (df1)
         Date Name
0  2012-11-26    a
1  2012-11-27    a
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#set-reset-index).

Comment: ty for ur quick response, I do spend a lot of time on it, I now understand I need to create a new df to get the result after reset index.